# Seaborn heatmap integer formatting

Tags: python, formatting, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heatmap plot with integers showing. As the numbers are quite high I was wondering if it is possible to write `k` instead of `000`? So `417924` would become `418k`.

```
confusion_matrix = ([[417924,  67554],
       [ 24901,  11070]])

x_axis_labels = ['predicted_non_churns','predicted_churns'] # labels for x-axis
y_axis_labels = ['actual_non_churns','actual_churns'] # labels for y-axis

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix',fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True, cmap="Purples",  
           xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=y_axis_labels, fmt='g', ax=ax) # font size
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own annotation with the `annot` parameter. Create a separate array with `'k'` and apply it to your heatmap. You'll need to set `fmt` to `''` as well:

```
rnd = np.round(confusion_matrix/1000).astype(int)
annot = np.char.add(rnd.astype(str), 'k')
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=annot, fmt='', cmap="Purples",  
            xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=y_axis_labels, ax=ax)
```